# How to plost the elements of a list - Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, plot

I want to count the most 10 most frequent amenities from my dataframe thus I executed this command

```
x = collections.Counter(listings_amsterdam['amenities'].str.split(',').explode('amenities')).most_common(10)
```

As output I am getting this:

```
[(' "Wifi"', 18122),
 (' "Essentials"', 17698),
 (' "Heating"', 17067),
 (' "Kitchen"', 15022),
 (' "Washer"', 13487),
 (' "Hangers"', 13375),
 (' "Smoke alarm"', 12836),
 (' "Iron"', 12544),
 (' "Shampoo"', 12443),
 (' "TV"', 10846)]
```

I want to plot this but I don't know how. I tried the command `x.plt.bar()` or `plt.bar(x.keys(),x.values())` but nothing of this worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.bar( [i[0] for i in x], [i[1] for i in x])
plt.show()
```

produces
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [(' "Wifi"', 18122),
 (' "Essentials"', 17698),
 (' "Heating"', 17067),
 (' "Kitchen"', 15022),
 (' "Washer"', 13487),
 (' "Hangers"', 13375),
 (' "Smoke alarm"', 12836),
 (' "Iron"', 12544),
 (' "Shampoo"', 12443),
 (' "TV"', 10846)]

x_val = [x[0] for x in data]
y_val = [x[1] for x in data]

plt.bar(x_val,y_val)
plt.show()
```

x is a list and not a pyplot object. So you should pass the values of x in plt object.